# Pygame classes difficulty

Tags: python, class, pygame

I know I posted before but this time I'm hoping to really mesh out all the basics of my code and hopefully get a better understanding of classes. Know that I'm very inexperienced with classes, so a lot of this will be really silly stuff. Here's my code

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        global player
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.pos=(350,200)
        self.image=pygame.image.load("arrowtest.png").convert()
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        screen=pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area=screen.get_rect()
        self.speed=10
        self.state="still"
        self.reinit()
```

I've got a

```
player = Player()
```

at the start of my main loop

and my blit is

```
screen.blit(player.image, player.pos)
```

I fixed that issue, but now my problem is when it comes to a part where I use a function to angle the sprite. In my player class is this

```
def angleplayer(self):
    mouse_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    dx=mouse_pos[0]-player_x
    dy=mouse_pos[1]-player_y
    rads=math.atan2(-dy, dx)
    rads %= 2*pi
    angle = math.degrees(rads)
    print angle
    rot_player.image=pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, angle-90)
```

But when I attempt to use this, eg

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        angleplayer()
```

it says angleplayer is not defined.

I'm guessing the answer will be fairly simple but looking forward to it.

thank you

Comment: angleplayer(**self**) is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there's no function `angleplayer` in the current scope.

Since the `angleplayer` function is part of your `Player` class, you have to call it through an instace of that class.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    player.angleplayer()
```

(you didn't show your complete code, I just guess `player` is accessible here.)

Comment: Thank you, this indeed worked, and the code runs but now I'm faced with a logic error where the sprite simply doesn't move regardless of input. I just put my source code into the original post so no context is left out. Is there a better way of moving the sprite apart from the blit? I've seen somewhere stuff about updating the sprite or some such, done quite differently to simply blit'ing it.

Thank you